# Is there a better way to restructure playbook without “include_tasks” and run task simultaneously?

Tags: ansible

I need a way to speed up my playbook, maybe better logical re-structuring. It’s running sequentially now. The task is simple – run playbook from AWX that will backup list of VMs.

I’m supplying a list of VMs in AWX extra variables:

```
backupList:
  - vmName: VM1
    backupAge: 2d
  - vmName: VM2
    backupAge: 5d
  - vmName: VM3
    backupAge: 1d
backupDirectory: /vmfs/volumes/NFS_BACKUPS
```

The first playbook is simple:

```
- name: Process VM backup here
  include_tasks: processBackup.yml
  vars:
    vm_name: "{{ item.vmName }}"
    backupAge: "{{ item.backupAge }}"
  with_items: "{{ backupList }}"
```

It reads extra variables and loops through calling second playbook using “include_tasks” where all functionality is written: cloning VM, copy to NFS server and making sure we keep the defined amount of backup copies.

Basically the same set of tasks performed with different VM names and backup age. In this configuration it is executed sequentially and takes long time, especially the copy to a backup server.

So, I'm wondering if there is a better way to restructure the code to run tasks simultaneously for each VM name?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I end up with and it works for my example.
I’ve created a group of hosts named “backup” in the AWX inventory with IPs for hostnames of those VMs that I need to backup. I moved extra variables from the template and placed them under each host in the group, so it looks like this (different values per IP):

```
---
vmName: VM1
backupAge: 2d
backupDirectory: /vmfs/volumes/NFS_BACKUPS
```

Now when ansible iterates throw the list of hosts in the “backup” group it also can access their own vars. Plus after enabling forking in the template I’ve got ansible’s natural threading capabilities.

My second playbook didn’t change, but first playbook (aka driver) changed a bit – I don’t need the “`with_items`” anymore:

```
- name: Backup VMs to NFS server
  hosts: backup
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:

    - name: Process VM backup here
      include_tasks: processBackup.yml
      vars:
        vm_name: "{{ vmName }}"
        backupAge: "{{ backupAge }}"
      delegate_to: localhost
```

Hope it will help someone :)